# Initialize Sparse Matrix during optimization

Tags: optimization

I have a matrix, $W$, which is `500,000 x 500,000` that I need to find to optimize over the following:

$W* = argmin _{W}|| AW - B||_F^2 + \lambda || W||_1^1$

Using an iterative methods, such as gradient descent. On my local machine I can't just initialize W randomly, instead I need to create a sparse matrix and then initialize some elements. Note that W* is sparse. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

From the `scipy` [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.rand.html#scipy.sparse.rand)

```
from scipy.sparse import rand
matrix = rand(500000, 500000, density=0.25, format="csr", random_state=42)
```

You can use the parameter `density` to choose how *dense* you want your matrix:

> density equal to one means a full matrix, density of 0 means a matrix
> with no non-zero items.

Comment: wouldn't that effect the optimization performance though?

Comment: In which sense? Did I answer the question on how "to create a sparse matrix and then initialize some elements"? Have you tried it?